Custom EDID for specfic physical monitor, not output [amd]
I have a setup where I connect to two different displays depending on where I am. I would like to use a mode which one of the monitors doesn't allow, but that won't be loaded when any other display is connected.
To be specific, whenever a specific monitor x is connected, use edid1.bin (e.g.) and for rest, use whatever supplied by the monitor/vendor.
The question is same as this one but for amd igpu.
I am able to use Forcing EDID and Kernel Params to set the usage of the edid1.bin file but it gets applied to every monitor that I connect via the same HDMI Port.
System:
HP Laptop
Model: EC1019AU
OS: Arch Linux
Driver:
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string" | cut -f2 -d":" | xargs
AMD

uname -r
6.9.6-arch1-1

